# How many Spring beans gets created in this case

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have a class called EmployeeService and which is annotated with @service annotation from spring framework

```
package com.sample.EmployeeService
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

}
```

and I also have entry in context.xml

```
<bean id="empSer" class ="com.sample.EmployeeService"
```

May I know how many bean has been created in psring container.

Comment: ***One . . .***

Comment: You will get only 1 bean as you have provided a single bean id in context.xml file.

Comment: As I annotated class with @Service annotation, won't it create bean with id="employeeService"

Comment: The correct answer is "it depends". If both context.xml gets processed AND autoscanning is active, then indeed you should get two beans, one called empSer and one employeeService.

Answer (score 0):

**In here**

Spring will scan all the classes with @Service  annotation, register it as a bean, then it will inject the dependencies that have @Autowired annotation.

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

}
```

**In here**

The context.xml is Spring's advanced container. Similar to BeanFactory, it can load bean definitions, wire beans together

```
<bean id="empSer" class ="com.sample.EmployeeService"
```

Actually you get one single bean - whether context.xml  it is loaded first or classes with @Service annotation

**And**

If first loaded context.xml and second loaded  @Service annotation class,   Spring Application  overwrite by default as the beans are being loaded up into the factory